# is_move_constructible and msvc2013

Tags: c++, c++11, move

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 

struct Foo 
{
    Foo(Foo&& f) = delete;
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value; // output is 1

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Under msv2013 should I forgot something, or is there a bug ?

**APPENDUM:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 

struct Foo 
{ 
    ~Foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value;

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

even with CTP this program produce an output of 1 (and c++ standard say the contrary), whereas the first example with CTP works fine.

Comment: @Mgetz: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20816117/560648

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it must be a bug.**

`is_move_constructible` is defined in terms of `is_constructible`, which requires that a construction with the given parameters is well-formed, which is clearly not the case here.

> `[C++11: Table 49]:` **`is_move_constructible<T>`**
>
> `is_constructible<T, T&&>::value` is true

> `[C++11: 20.9.4.3/6]:` Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(create<Args>()...);
> ```

<sup>(A note that follows clarifies that `create` is used here to avoid the Most Vexing Parse for all `Args`.)</sup>

For the record, [the output is `0` with GCC 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42d0e49750910459).

---

A similar bug with `is_*constructible` relating to abstract classes [appears to have been fixed in mid-2013](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808132/std-is-constructible-t-value-true-for-abstract-classes), and [here's another one](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799505/c-type-traits-seem-to-ignore-accessibility-modifiers):

> Posted by Microsoft on 18/09/2013 at 13:17 Hi,
>
> Thanks for reporting this bug. We've fixed it, and the fix is available in VS 2013 RC.
>
> In fact, we've overhauled , fixing all known bugs. You can read more about this here:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx
>
> Stephan T. Lavavej
>   Senior Developer - Visual C++ Libraries
>   stl@microsoft.com

The changelog behind that link includes the following fix:

> the is_constructible family of type traits behaving incorrectly with references (DevDiv#517460)

So, give this a go again in MSVS's November 2013 CTP.

**Update:** I'm told that this *is* fixed in the November CTP. Thanks [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) for testing.

Comment: Sorry, I provided a wrong information (messed up with project settings). It seems to be fixed in November 2013's CTP.

Comment: besides i think msvc2013 still doesn"t generate an implicit move ctor

Comment: @Guillaume07: Indeed it doesn't. The CTP fixed that.

Comment: @Andy: but even with the CTP, if I declare `struct Foo` with a trivial destructor `std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value` return me true. And I believed than c++ standard establish than when a destructor is declared no implicit move ctor is generated

Comment: @Guillaume07: That's how it should be, yes. Before they were never implicitly generating move-constructors and move-assignment operators, now they generate them too often. It's a swinging pendulum, hopefully VC13 will get this right :)

Comment: @Guillaume07: Actually, the reason why it returns `true` is that there is an implicitly generated copy constructor, and a copy-constructible class is also move-constructible. Now the implicit generation of a copy constructor is only deprecated, not illegal (because of backwards compatibility), so the CTP's behavior is still compliant. Try deleting the copy constructor: `std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value` should then yield `false`.

Comment: @Andy: ok I ignore the consequence of a copy-constructible class. Besides If I only declare the move-ctor + default ctor and attempt to copy Foo, MSVC2013 tell me that Foo(const Foo&) is deleted.

Comment: @Guillaume07: That's because a user-declared move constructor inhibits the implicit generation of a copy constructor (12.8/7). Here, however, implicit generation is not deprecated but invalid: backwards compatibility does not apply, because move constructors did not exist before C++11 (more precisely, the copy constructor is implicitly defined as deleted).

Comment: @Andy:all right so there is the following asymmetry: a  copy-constructible class is also move-constructible but a move-constructible class is not copy-constructible (except if user explicitly define both ctor).

Comment: @Guillaume07: That's one of those areas where I think the Standard is quite misleading. The `MoveConstructible` concept means that you should be able to construct the object from an rvalue. The `CopyConstructible` concept means you should be able to construct the object from an lvalue. Now since a copy constructor accepts its argument by `const&` (let's forget about weird copy constructors that don't), you can pass an rvalue to it. You will get a copy, but that makes the class `MoveConstructible`.

Comment: @Guillaume07: Another way to think about it is in terms of state propagation. Copy is a way of propagating state from object X to object Y so that (1) object Y assumes the state of object X, and (2) object X retains its state. After the copy, both objects have the same state. Move is a way of propagating state that only requires (1), and that makes it more general. This is why `CopyConstructible` is a specialization of `MoveConstructible`, and not vice versa. This concept of "move" conflicts with the notion of "move" as "invoking the move constructor", and the Standard does not disambiguate.

Comment: @AndyProwl:thanks for these explanations, very clear.